# Fourier Analysis question on convolution

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution

Let $f(x) = \operatorname{sinc}(x)^2$. Find $(f*f)(x)$?

This is what I tried

$f(x)=\mathrm{sinc}(x)^2$
$$
\begin{align}
f\ast f(x)
&=\int f(u)\cdot f(x-u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\mathrm{sinc}(u)^2\cdot\mathrm{sinc}(x-u)^2\,\mathrm{d}u\\
\end{align}
$$
Since $\mathrm{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.
I have no clue what to do after this?

Comment: It helps to provide some context for the problem. What have you tried, and what do you need help with specifically?

Comment: I am kinda stuck. I tried to put in the equation:
int(f(u)-f(x-u) du but am not sure how to integrate by parts.

Comment: Try editing your question and adding what you tried, it makes people more helpful here :) I would help, but I haven't taken fourier-analysis

Comment: It's good that you included your solution attempt, but it is hard to read this way. Better to type the formulas in. Since your title mentions Fourier analysis: Do you know the relation between the Fourier transform and convolution? If not, look it up.

Comment: I know the relation but its the integration by parts i am confused on!!

Comment: I can't read sideways.

Comment: Where does the Fourier analysis come in?

Comment: @copper.hat: my guess is that the problem is from a section or book on Fourier analysis. There is a way to compute the convolution using Fourier analysis.

Comment: @AJAYASHRESTHA: which integration by parts? I don't see any integration by parts attempted in your work.

Comment: @AJAYASHRESTHA, if you know the relation, you don't need integration by parts.

Answer (score 4):

We can use the Fourier Transform to ease some of the work
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^ae^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{-2\pi i\xi}\left(e^{-2\pi ia\xi}-e^{2\pi ia\xi}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\sin(2\pi a\xi)}{\pi\xi}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the Fourier Transform of $\overbrace{\pi\left[|\xi|\le\frac1{2\pi}\right]}^\chi$ is $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$, where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

and the Fourier Transform of $\overbrace{\pi\left(1-\pi|\xi|\right)\left[|\xi|\le\frac1\pi\right]}^{\chi\ast\chi}$ is $\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)$

and the Fourier Transform of $\overbrace{\pi^2\left(1-\pi|\xi|\right)^2\left[|\xi|\le\frac1\pi\right]}^{(\chi\ast\chi)^2}$ is $\mathrm{sinc}^2\!\ast\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)$

Apply the inverse Fourier Transform
$$
\begin{align}
\pi^2\int_{-1/\pi}^{1/\pi}(1-\pi|\xi|)^2e^{2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}\xi
&=\pi^2\int_{-1/\pi}^{1/\pi}(1-\pi|\xi|)^2\cos(2\pi x\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=2\pi^2\int_0^{1/\pi}(1-\pi\xi)^2\cos(2\pi x\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=2\pi\int_0^1(1-\xi)^2\cos(2x\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{x}\int_0^1(1-\xi)\sin(2x\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\frac\pi{x^2}-\frac{\pi}{x^2}\int_0^1\cos(2x\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A000]{\frac{\pi(x-\sin(x)\cos(x))}{x^3}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: is that pi or the box function??

Comment: I am not sure what you asking about. The $\pi$ above is the ratio of the circumference to the diameter of a circle. If you are asking about $[\cdots]$, those are [Iverson Brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: just wondering how that pi came  from??

Comment: There are a number of $\pi$s above. Which is the one that is confusing?

Comment: Is there a way without using inverse transform?

Comment: If we use the Fourier Transform to put things into the frequency domain, we need to use the Inverse Fourier Transform to get things back into the time domain. So, to avoid using the Inverse Fourier Transform, we would need to avoid using the Fourier Transform.